# How to get the numbers of rows from a pl/sql cursor without opening it?

Tags: plsql, count, cursor

Imagine declaring a pl/sql cursor. Usually you would open it, fetch the records and in the end ROWCOUNT will tell about the number of records retrieved. But is there a way to get this number of records only when having declared a cursor? Or do I always have to go through all the records to reach my goal?

I' m asking because I need something like that: Go through the cursor and fetch one record after the other but right from the beginning I have to know how much records it will retrieve in complete. This should answer a question like: right now I' m working with record 1 of 5. I' ve solved this problem by using a SELECT COUNT(*) INTO (with the same SELECT-clause the Cursor is build of) and it works but isn' t there a better way to do so? Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Imagine you have an opaque bag containing marbles. You want to take all or the red marbles out of the bag, but you want to know how many red marbles there are before you take them out. How would you go about solving this problem? When you can do that, you can solve the problem of knowing how many rows a cursor will return before you fetch the results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get count of ref cursor in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205530/get-count-of-ref-cursor-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're looking for but this might do the trick:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ..., columnN, 
       rownum current_row, 
       count(1) over () total 
FROM table
WHERE ....;
```

This way, when you're going through the cursor you will always know the number of the record you're working with and the total of records.